# How to find the indexes of all occurrences of an element in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to find the indexes of all the instances of an element, say, "Nano", in a JavaScript array.

```
var Cars = ["Nano", "Volvo", "BMW", "Nano", "VW", "Nano"];
```

I tried [jQuery.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/), or similarly, [.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), but it only gave the index of the last instance of the element, i.e. 5 in this case.

How do I get it for all instances?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

The [`.indexOf()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) has an optional second parameter that specifies the index to start searching from, so you can call it in a loop to find all instances of a particular value:

```
function getAllIndexes(arr, val) {
    var indexes = [], i = -1;
    while ((i = arr.indexOf(val, i+1)) != -1){
        indexes.push(i);
    }
    return indexes;
}

var indexes = getAllIndexes(Cars, "Nano");
```

You don't really make it clear how you want to use the indexes, so my function returns them as an array (or returns an empty array if the value isn't found), but you could do something else with the individual index values inside the loop.

UPDATE: As per VisioN's comment, a simple for loop would get the same job done more efficiently, and it is easier to understand and therefore easier to maintain:

```
function getAllIndexes(arr, val) {
    var indexes = [], i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if (arr[i] === val)
            indexes.push(i);
    return indexes;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the faster alternative to a single `for` loop with index array populating.

Comment: @VisioN - Yes, a plain for loop iterating over the array would be simpler too, but since the OP mentioned trying to use `.indexOf()` I wanted to show that it can do the job. (I guess I figured the OP could figure out how to do it with a for loop.) Of course there are other ways to do it, e.g., `Cars.reduce(function(a, v, i) { if (v==="Nano") a.push(i); return a; }, []);`

Comment: I can tell you're from North America because you used `indexes` instead of `indices` :P

Comment: @4castle - Ha. No, I'm not. "Indices" and "indexes" are both correct, and I tend to alternate between the two. I hadn't ever thought of that as a regional dialect thing. Interesting.

Comment: Note that the first example given works great for strings and arrays. The second only works for arrays.

Comment: I believe `.map()` would be more concise

Comment: @WebDegBrian - `.map()` returns an array the same length as the one it was called on, so you'd also need to use `.filter()` with it. Better to use `.reduce()` as per VisionN's answer.

Comment: @SethWhite - Sure, but the question was about arrays. (The second one does work to find occurrences of individual characters, but not longer substrings.)

Comment: It's not good to calculate `arr.length` at each loop, place it before `for` statement or in the first part of `for`,for example
`for (let i=0,len=arr.length;i<len;i++){...}`

Comment: @IgorFomenko - Thanks for the suggestion.  It's not really a "calculation", it's just a property lookup, but still actually I do often code loops as per your suggestion, but I don't usually do it in StackOverflow answers if it's not directly relevant to the question. How sure are you that the JS compiler won't do that optimisation automatically behind the scenes?

Comment: @nnnnnn - I've got this information from some book or w3school or another internet source

Comment: The `indexOf` recommendation right at the top of the thread in this post is fundamentally inefficient and should be removed. `indexOf` is simply the wrong tool for the job. Use the bottom version or something more idiomatic in one of the answers below this. Regarding "caching" `array.length`--this is a silly micro-optimization that harms readability and introduces potentially subtle and difficult-to-find bugs with virtually no performance benefit. `array.length` is a hashtable lookup, not `strlen` in C that traverses the whole structure item by item.

Comment: @ggorlen - Thanks for the comment. As mentioned in my first comment above, I originally included `indexOf` because the OP mentioned it and so I was just showing a way to make it work without the specific issue OP mentioned. I agree it's not actually a good way to solve the underlying problem, hence the update that doesn't use it, but I'm not going to remove it altogether because I don't like to substantially alter an answer after it was accepted (especially this long after it was accepted).

Comment: If we want to use the same function on a string (for example, to get the locations of white spaces), will the for loop still be a faster alternative?

Answer (score 132):

Another alternative solution is to use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
["Nano","Volvo","BMW","Nano","VW","Nano"].reduce(function(a, e, i) {
    if (e === 'Nano')
        a.push(i);
    return a;
}, []);   // [0, 3, 5]
```

**N.B.:** Check the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Browser_compatibility) for `reduce` method and use [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill) if required.

Comment: +1. Funny coincidence: I just edited my reply to your comment under my answer to suggest exactly this solution, then I refresh and see you'd already coded the same thing with only one variable name different.

Comment: @nnnnnn `:)` Yeah, I thought maybe `reduce` could be a nice alternative.

Comment: `array.reduce((a, e, i) => (e === value) ? a.concat(i) : a, [])`

Comment: I googled `contat` is slower than `push`, therefore I stick with the answer.

Comment: Yes, please don't use `concat` here--you're allocating a whole new array object on every callback and tossing the previous object into the garbage collector without any commensurate benefit in readability.

Comment: Then regarding @yckart and @ggorlen: `array.reduce((a, e, i) => (e === value) ? a.push(i) : a, [])`

Comment: The @Darkproduct solution will not work.  The push method return a number (the length of the array) and not the array itself. So it will raise an error. See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 95):

Another approach using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) and [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter):

```
var indices = array.map((e, i) => e === value ? i : '').filter(String)
```

Comment: great, it works. can you explain what is the role of the filter(String)

Comment: @Muthu `map(…)` checks on each iteration for the equality of `e` and `value`. When they match the index is returned, otherwise an empty string. To get rid of those falsy values, `filter(String)` makes sure that the result only contains values that are type of string and NOT empty.
`filter(String)` could also be written as: `filter(e => e !== '')`

Comment: ...or: `String(thing)` coerces anything to a string. `Array#filter` returns an array of all the values for which the condition is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). Because empty strings are [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), those are NOT included in the array.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it's really helpful for me

Comment: I would be confused if I saw this in a project. It reads like "Filter to strings", meaning only keep if it's a string. And then the resulting array would be indexes as strings, not numbers.

Comment: A real hero here. Thank you +1

Comment: Use `filter(Number)` instead of `filter(String)`. It needs less thinking.

Comment: This the way usually this is done is using `Boolean` ->  `filter(Boolean)`. `filter(Some callback return true or false)`

Comment: Don't use `filter(Number)` @Friedrich--СлаваУкраїні because 0 is equal to false, better to use `filter(String)` because 0 is a type of string.

Comment: @TopMarx 0 is also of type number, hence zero indices are also extracted.

Comment: @Friedrich--СлаваУкраїні the example in OP doesn't work using Number, it returns [3,5] whereas using String correctly gives [0,3,5]

Comment: @Friedrich--СлаваУкраїні https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53920037/why-does-array-filternumber-filter-zero-out-in-javascript

Comment: @Friedrich--СлаваУкраїні but you are correct, I was wrong, 0 is a type of number. The reason 0 is filtered out is because it's a falsy value

Answer (score 38):

More simple way with es6 style.

```
const indexOfAll = (arr, val) => arr.reduce((acc, el, i) => (el === val ? [...acc, i] : acc), []);


//Examples:
var cars = ["Nano", "Volvo", "BMW", "Nano", "VW", "Nano"];
indexOfAll(cars, "Nano"); //[0, 3, 5]
indexOfAll([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 1); // [0,3]
indexOfAll([1, 2, 3], 4); // []
```

Answer (score 35):

You can write a simple readable solution to this by using both `map` and `filter`:

```
const nanoIndexes = Cars
  .map((car, i) => car === 'Nano' ? i : -1)
  .filter(index => index !== -1);
```

---

EDIT: If you don't need to support IE/Edge (or are transpiling your code), ES2019 gave us [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), which lets you do this in a simple one-liner:

```
const nanoIndexes = Cars.flatMap((car, i) => car === 'Nano' ? i : []);
```

Comment: I liked this answer. But how about: changing to this:
`.map((car, i) => car === 'Nano' ? i : null).filter(i => i);`

Comment: Either works. The problem with using a non-number like null is it will make typing it in TypeScript much more annoying. If you are just using JavaScript, null works fine.

Answer (score 12):

I just want to update with another easy method.

You can also use forEach method.

```
var Cars = ["Nano", "Volvo", "BMW", "Nano", "VW", "Nano"];

var result = [];

Cars.forEach((car, index) => car === 'Nano' ? result.push(index) : null)
```

Answer (score 6):

Note: MDN gives a [method using a while loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
var indices = [];
var array = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'd'];
var element = 'a';
var idx = array.indexOf(element);
while (idx != -1) {
  indices.push(idx);
  idx = array.indexOf(element, idx + 1);
}
```

I wouldn't say it's any better than other answers. Just interesting.

Answer (score 5):

```
const indexes = cars
    .map((car, i) => car === "Nano" ? i : null)
    .filter(i => i !== null)
```

Comment: Indexes are zero-based, so this will fail if the first car is a Nano.

Comment: Oh look, you have a solution and mine looks like just like it. I should have seen yours before I spent time writing mine. There were just so many sprawling for loops I thought, "I could make my own answer in 2 seconds."

Comment: Yeah. These are mostly way over-complicated. Nice correction.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
let array1 = [5, 12, 8, 130, 44, 12, 45, 12, 56];
let numToFind = 12
let indexesOf12 = [] // the number whose occurrence in the array we want to find

array1.forEach(function(elem, index, array) {
    if (elem === numToFind) {indexesOf12.push(index)}
    return indexesOf12
})

console.log(indexesOf12) // outputs [1, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) will be useful:

```js
var cars = ['Nano', 'Volvo', 'BMW', 'Nano', 'VW', 'Nano'];

const indexes = [];
const searchedItem = 'NaNo';

cars.findIndex((value, index) => {
  if (value.toLowerCase() === searchedItem.toLowerCase()) {
    indexes.push(index);
  }
});

console.log(indexes); //[ 0, 3, 5 ]
```

Bonus:

This custom solution using `Object.entries()` and `forEach()`

```js
var cars = ['Nano', 'Volvo', 'BMW', 'Nano', 'VW', 'Nano'];

const indexes = [];
const searchableItem = 'Nano';

Object.entries(cars).forEach((item, index) => {
  if (item[1].toLowerCase() === searchableItem.toLowerCase())
    indexes.push(index);
});

console.log(indexes);
```

**Note:** I did not run run all tests

Answer (score 1):

Just to share another method, you can use [Function Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) to achieve the result as well:

```js
function findAllIndexOf(target, needle) {
  return [].concat(...(function*(){
    for (var i = 0; i < target.length; i++) if (target[i] === needle) yield [i];
  })());
}

var target = "hellooooo";
var target2 = ['w','o',1,3,'l','o'];

console.log(findAllIndexOf(target, 'o'));
console.log(findAllIndexOf(target2, 'o'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
["a", "b", "a", "b"]
   .map((val, index) => ({ val, index }))
   .filter(({val, index}) => val === "a")
   .map(({val, index}) => index)

=> [0, 2]
```

Comment: Please write an essential explanation or inline comments for the code. BTW, your solution did work but it contains 3 iterations...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Polyfill

```
if (!Array.prototype.filterIndex) 
{
    Array.prototype.filterIndex = function (func, thisArg) {

        'use strict';
        if (!((typeof func === 'Function' || typeof func === 'function') && this))
            throw new TypeError();

        let len = this.length >>> 0,
            res = new Array(len), // preallocate array
            t = this, c = 0, i = -1;

        let kValue;
        if (thisArg === undefined) {
            while (++i !== len) {
                // checks to see if the key was set
                if (i in this) {
                    kValue = t[i]; // in case t is changed in callback
                    if (func(t[i], i, t)) {
                        res[c++] = i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            while (++i !== len) {
                // checks to see if the key was set
                if (i in this) {
                    kValue = t[i];
                    if (func.call(thisArg, t[i], i, t)) {
                        res[c++] = i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        res.length = c; // shrink down array to proper size
        return res;
    };
}
```

Use it like this:

```
[2,23,1,2,3,4,52,2].filterIndex(element => element === 2)

result: [0, 3, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

`findIndex` retrieves only the first index which matches callback output. You can implement your own `findIndexes` by extending Array , then casting your arrays to the new structure .

```js
class EnhancedArray extends Array {
  findIndexes(where) {
    return this.reduce((a, e, i) => (where(e, i) ? a.concat(i) : a), []);
  }
}
   /*----Working with simple data structure (array of numbers) ---*/

//existing array
let myArray = [1, 3, 5, 5, 4, 5];

//cast it :
myArray = new EnhancedArray(...myArray);

//run
console.log(
   myArray.findIndexes((e) => e===5)
)
/*----Working with Array of complex items structure-*/

let arr = [{name: 'Ahmed'}, {name: 'Rami'}, {name: 'Abdennour'}];

arr= new EnhancedArray(...arr);


console.log(
  arr.findIndexes((o) => o.name.startsWith('A'))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use Stack and push "i" into the stack every time we encounter the condition "arr[i]==value"

Check this:

```
static void getindex(int arr[], int value)
{
    Stack<Integer>st= new Stack<Integer>();
    int n= arr.length;
    for(int i=n-1; i>=0 ;i--)
    {
        if(arr[i]==value)
        {
            st.push(i);
        }
    }   
    while(!st.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println(st.peek()+" ");
        st.pop(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged with `javascript`, whilst your answer is `Java` I believe?

Answer (score 0):

When both parameter passed as array

```
    function getIndexes(arr, val) {
        var indexes = [], i;
        for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for(j =0; j< val.length; j++) {
     if (arr[i] === val[j])
                indexes.push(i);
    }
    }    
        return indexes;
    }
```