# Testing an array of strings indexOf against another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array of characters I am testing another array against. The array of strings length can dynamically change every time the app is ran. Here is the code I have, but right now it is just going through the first index of the array. How can I have it go through all the length of the array `toTest`

code:

```
var testAgainst = ['and','+',',','&'];
var toTest = ['This is just a test +','This is just a test and','This is just a test ,','This is just a test &','This is just a test'];

for(var i = 0; i < testAgainst.length; i++){

    if (toTest[0].indexOf(testAgainst[i]) > -1){
        console.log('match: ' + testAgainst[i]);
    }else{
        console.log('no match');
    }

}
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/bmpgsxb2/2/

Comment: Use a nested for-loop for `toTest`.

Comment: here is another solution for this case [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798477/how-to-find-index-of-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add a for-loop to go through each element in the `toTest` array like so:

```
for(var i = 0; i < testAgainst.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < toTest.length; j++){
        if (toTest[j].indexOf(testAgainst[i]) > -1){
            console.log('match: ' + testAgainst[i]);
        }else{
            console.log('no match');
        }
    }
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bmpgsxb2/3/)