# How to find index of all occurrences of an element in array (Ramda.js way)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ramda.js

I am trying to find index of all the instances let's say `Header` and `Footer` in an array.

```
var arr = [
'data',
'data',
'data',
'data',
'Header',
'data',
'data',
'data',
'Footer',
'data',
'Header',
'data',
'Footer',
'data'
];
```

I know how to do this in plain JS ([How to find index of all occurrences of element in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798477/how-to-find-index-of-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-array)), but I wonder how it would be done in FP, `ramda.js` in particular?

I know how to do this for first instance `R.findIndex(R.test(_regexForHeader))` but can not wrap my head around looping through all array. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@pierrebeitz's answer is on point, namely that when you need access to indices while iterating over a list you'll typically zip the list up along with its indices. Ramda provides an [R.addIndex](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#addIndex) function for modifying functions like `map` to provide the index along with each element while iterating.

The nesting in his example can also be replaced with a composition pipeline if you prefer:

```
const zipWithIndex = addIndex(map)(pair);

const isHeaderOrFooter = either(equals('Header'), equals('Footer'));

const hfIndices = pipe(
  zipWithIndex,
  filter(pipe(head, isHeaderOrFooter)),
  map(nth(1))
);

hfIndices(arr);
```

One thing to be mindful of with both of these approaches is you'll end up iterating over the list multiple times. This won't typically be a problem for a small list, however for larger lists you might want to consider using [R.into](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#into) which effectively fuses the maps and filter together into a transducer that will now take only a single pass over the list (see http://simplectic.com/blog/2015/ramda-transducers-logs/ for a good intro to transducers).

This can be achieved with a small tweak to `hfIndices` in the above example by swapping the composition from `pipe` to `compose` (transducer functions compose in the opposite order) and wrapping it with `into`.

```
const hfIndices = into([], compose(
  zipWithIndex,
  filter(pipe(head, isHeaderOrFooter)),
  map(nth(1))
));
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm not THAT into FP but i believe you have to "generate" the data you want to work with. you have to add an index to afterwards apply your filter:

```
 var arr = ['data', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'Header', 'data', 'data', 'data', 'Footer', 'data', 'Header', 'data', 'Footer', 'data'];

R.map((e) => e[1], 
  R.filter(val => val[0] == 'Header' || val[0] == 'Footer', 
    R.addIndex(R.map)((e, i) => [e,i], arr)
  )
);
// => [4, 8, 10, 12]
```

This is not the most elaborate solution, but it should get you going!