# Multiple values having same text not getting the exact selected text offsets

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a text which is like ->

> **Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.**

Now, I want to highlight some part of this text, so I need to know the start and end offsets of the string.

Let's say

```
it to make a
```

This is the text I want to highlight, so I need the offset of this text; so far I tried using the following logic

```
var startoffset  = $scope.original_doc_content.indexOf("it to make a ");
var endoffset =  startoffset + string.length;
```

Now my issue is happening if `it to make a` is present 2 times in the given text: if I want to highlight or want to take the second one and if it's present before the 2nd one then it gives me the 1st ones offset and not the second one which I require. So how can I resolve this?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript indexOf method with multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631641/javascript-indexof-method-with-multiple-values)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find index of all occurrences of element in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798477/how-to-find-index-of-all-occurrences-of-element-in-array)

Comment: This might be duplicate but can u tell me how can i get the correct offset , which I have clicked or selected that text

Comment: @TemaniAfifI know index of usage , but I was asking How will I come to know is the same which I have selected.

Comment: One thing is that i don't have any array I have a document which you can say a resume , I have to find in that document.

Answer (score 0):

You can do highlighting a lot easier with a simple replace.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var str = document.getElementById("mypar").innerText;
  var res = str.replace(/text/g, "<span class=\"highlight\">text</span>");
  document.getElementById("mypar").innerHTML = res;
};
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p id="mypar">This is my text where i want to highlight text or something</p>
```

Or you can do this to get the index. It's probably not the best solution but it works. It iterates over the words until it can not find more and logs the values to the console.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var str = document.getElementById("mypar").innerText;
  var indexFirstChar = 0;
  var indexOfLastChar = 0;
  var searchString = "text";
  while(str.indexOf(searchString, indexFirstChar + 1) >= 0) {
     indexFirstChar = str.indexOf(searchString, indexFirstChar + 1);
     indexOfLastChar = indexFirstChar + searchString.length - 1;
     console.log(indexFirstChar);
     console.log(indexOfLastChar);
  }
};
```

```html
<p id="mypar">This is my text where i want to highlight text or something</p>
```

Comment: I already have my own highlighting logic i just need to know the offset of that perfect position

Comment: @ganeshkaspate Updated my answer with a index snippet.

Comment: @ganeshkaspate All code affects performance. I'm far from an expert on this subject but it might become slow when searching in very large texts. My first example with a replace function is probably a better solution. Some performance testing would need to be done to confirm my theory though.