# Javascript - How can I perform this string manipulation using regex more cleanly/effeciently?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have the following string:

> [SM_g]This[SM_h][SM_g]is[SM_h][SM_g]a[SM_h][SM_g]sentence.[SM_h][SM_l][SM_g]Here[SM_h][SM_g]is[SM_h][SM_g]another[SM_h][SM_g]sentence.[SM_h][SM_1]

And I can turn that string into this string, which I then display within a `<p>` element:

> This is a sentence.
>
> Here is another sentence.

with the following code:

```js
tokenResponseText_initial = "[SM_g]This[SM_h][SM_g]is[SM_h][SM_g]a[SM_h][SM_g]sentence.[SM_h][SM_l][SM_g]Here[SM_h][SM_g]is[SM_h][SM_g]another[SM_h][SM_g]sentence.[SM_h][SM_1]"

const newLineIndicator = "insert-double-new-line"

const tokenResponseText_fixedNewLines = tokenResponseText_initial.replace(/(\[SM_g].*?)(\[SM_h]\[SM_l])/g, "$1" + newLineIndicator + "$2");

const wordCompilationRegex = /\[SM_g](.*?)\[SM_h]/g;
var wordRegexResponse;

var summary = "";

do {
  wordRegexResponse = wordCompilationRegex.exec(tokenResponseText_fixedNewLines);
  if (wordRegexResponse) {
    if (wordRegexResponse[1].includes(newLineIndicator)) {
      summary += wordRegexResponse[1].replace(newLineIndicator, "") + "\n\n";
    } else {
      summary += wordRegexResponse[1] + " ";
    }
  }
} while (wordRegexResponse);
//The following is rough code, 
someParagraphElement.innerHTML = summary;
```

```css
p {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<p id="someParagraphElement"></p>
```

Where the paragraph element has the following attribute `white-space: pre-line;`

However, ideally, in order to create the double newline between the two sentences, I'd like to eliminate the use of `newLineIndicator` and simply do this:

But, this second method does not work. The end result does not end having the double new lines *even though* when I print `tokenResponseText_fixedNewLines` to the console, it seems like the double new lines have been inserted, like so:

> [SM_g]This[SM_h][SM_g]is[SM_h][SM_g]a[SM_h][SM_g]sentence.
>
> [SM_h][SM_l][SM_g]Here[SM_h][SM_g]is[SM_h][SM_g]another[SM_h][SM_g]sentence.[SM_h][SM_1]

```js
tokenResponseText_initial = "[SM_g]This[SM_h][SM_g]is[SM_h][SM_g]a[SM_h][SM_g]sentence.[SM_h][SM_l][SM_g]Here[SM_h][SM_g]is[SM_h][SM_g]another[SM_h][SM_g]sentence.[SM_h][SM_1]"

const tokenResponseText_fixedNewLines = tokenResponseText_initial.replace(/(\[SM_g].*?)(\[SM_h]\[SM_l])/g, "$1\n\n$2");

const wordCompilationRegex = /\[SM_g](.*?)\[SM_h]/g;
var wordRegexResponse;

var summary = "";

do {
  wordRegexResponse = wordCompilationRegex.exec(tokenResponseText_fixedNewLines);
  if (wordRegexResponse) {
    summary += wordRegexResponse[1] + " ";

  }
} while (wordRegexResponse);
//The following is rough code, 
someParagraphElement.innerHTML = summary;
```

```css
p {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<p id="someParagraphElement"></p>
```

Why does the second method not work, although the first method does work? Does `.*?` not capture new lines?

Comment: Are all `[SM_x]` to be replaced with a single space or are some to be replaced with other characters? Can you help indicate what each of these codes should be replaced with?

Comment: The [SM_x] are not actually replaced - rather, I use a do/while construct in order to compile all of the words in between each [SM_x] into a single string as shown in the example. Whenever there is a `[SM_g]word[SM_h][SM_l]`, the regex (in the second example) turns it into `[SM_g]word\n\n[SM_h][SM_l]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `.` doesn't match newlines. So when you insert the newlines into the string with the first `.replace()`, some of the `[SM_g]word[SM_h]` sequences no longer match `wordCompilationRegex`.

You can use the `s` modifier to allow `.` to match newlines.

**Oops** This is a Chrome extension, not a Javascript standard flag. Use `[\s\S]` instead of `.`.

```js
tokenResponseText_initial = "[SM_g]This[SM_h][SM_g]is[SM_h][SM_g]a[SM_h][SM_g]sentence.[SM_h][SM_l][SM_g]Here[SM_h][SM_g]is[SM_h][SM_g]another[SM_h][SM_g]sentence.[SM_h][SM_1]"

const tokenResponseText_fixedNewLines = tokenResponseText_initial.replace(/(\[SM_g].*?)(\[SM_h]\[SM_l])/g, "$1\n\n$2");

const wordCompilationRegex = /\[SM_g]([\s\S]*?)\[SM_h]/g;
var wordRegexResponse;

var summary = "";

do {
  wordRegexResponse = wordCompilationRegex.exec(tokenResponseText_fixedNewLines);
  if (wordRegexResponse) {
    summary += wordRegexResponse[1] + " ";

  }
} while (wordRegexResponse);
//The following is rough code, 
someParagraphElement.innerHTML = summary;
```

```css
p {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<p id="someParagraphElement"></p>
```

Comment: Running the answer (in stack overflow at least) gives an error saying `"SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag s"`

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: Oh, huh, it failed to work in firefox quantam (but I checked and it worked in chrome). I don't know if that will be a problem, considering this code is for a web extension that should work in chrome or firefox.

Comment: Apparently the `s` flag is not standard, it's a Chrome extension.

Comment: Oh, that's problematic, do you know of ways to do this without a chrome specific extension?

Comment: Updated the answer. Use `[\s\S]` instead of `.`.

Answer (score 0):

Your new code isn't putting a newline between the sentences because there is nothing in your code that would do that.

What you want to do is 1) detect if there is a new sentence.  2) When there is a new sentence, insert two new lines between them.

1. In order to detect a new sentence, use `let index = summary.indexOf('.')` and if the  index is not --1 and is not equal to the `summary.length - 1` (that is, the last character of the string), then you have detected there is at least two sentences.
2. If you have detected that there are two sentences, then inserting the newlines between them is a simple matter of [using `array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Note: if you need to handle there possibly being more than two sentences, then I would recommend writing the code to handle two sentences (as I have outlined above) and then amending it to loop through all indexes [as the first answer to this question explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798477/how-to-find-index-of-all-occurrences-of-element-in-array).

If you get into writing your code and get stuck/have more questions, just comment on this answer and I'll respond.