# Javascript - Get indices of true values in a boolean array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have an array with the following values -

```
var arr = [true, true, false, false, false, true, false];
```

I'm looking for logic which will give me the following output -

```
[0,1,5]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find index of all occurrences of element in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798477/how-to-find-index-of-all-occurrences-of-element-in-array)

Comment: You should also post your own effort with the post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to do this in one pass:

```js
const arr = [true, true, false, false, false, true, false]
const indices = arr.reduce(
  (out, bool, index) => bool ? out.concat(index) : out, 
  []
)
console.log(indices)
```

You start by passing an empty array `[]` as the `initialValue` to `.reduce()` and use a [ternary `?` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to determine whether to [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) the `index` or not.

---

Alternatively, you can use the more recent [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) method:

```js
const arr = [true, true, false, false, false, true, false]
const indices = arr.flatMap((bool, index) => bool ? index : [])
console.log(indices)
```

If your browser does not yet support it, you'll get an `Uncaught TypeError: arr.flatMap is not a function`. In that case, you can use my polyfill definition from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58355999/1541563).

Answer (score 4):

A potentially more elegant solution is:

```
[...arr.keys()].filter(i => arr[i])
```

or alternatively

```
[...arr.entries()].filter(([, v]) => v).map(([i]) => i)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could map the indices or for falsy values `-1` and then filter all indices which are not `-1`.

```js
var array = [true, true, false, false, false, true, false],
    result = array
        .map((b, i) => b ? i : -1)
        .filter(i => i !== -1);
        
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a loop and check the boolean value `true` in your `if` condition:

```js
var arr = [true, true, false, false, false, true, false];
var indexArray = [];
arr.forEach((val, index) => {
  if(val){
    indexArray.push(index);
  }
});

console.log(indexArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```js
var arr = [true, true, false, false, false, true, false];
var indexArray = [];
arr.forEach(function(value, index) {
    if (value) {
        indexArray.push(index);
    }
})
console.log(indexArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

**Different solution based on logic itself and not JS paradigms**

```
let newArr = [];
for (let i = 0 ; i<indexArray.length;i++){
    if (indexArray[i]) newArr.push(i)
}
```