# transform array of object into new array following with its child

Tags: javascript, arrays, arrayobject

i have an array like this

```
var data = [
    {
        name: "Movies", info: "category_name",
        content: [
            { name: "Interstellar", info: "category_data" },
            { name: "Dark Knight", info: "category_data" },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Music", info: "category_name",
        content: [
            { name: "Adams", info: "category_data" },
            { name: "Nirvana", info: "category_data" },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Places", info: "category_name",
        content: [
            { name: "Jordan", info: "category_data" },
            { name: "Punjab", info: "category_data" },
        ]
    },
]
```

and a want to transform it into like this

```
var transformedArray= [
  { name: "Movies", info: "category_name" },
  { name: "Interstellar", info: "category_data" },
  { name: "Dark Knight", info: "category_data" },
  { name: "Music", info: "category_name" },
  { name: "Adams", info: "category_data" },
  { name: "Nirvana", info: "category_data" },
  { name: "Places", info: "category_name" },
  { name: "Jordan", info: "category_data" },
  { name: "Punjab", info: "category_data" },
]
```

i dont know what is the keyword suitable for this case ,
i have tried mapping it into new array but it's not same like i expected

```
var newArr = []

var manipulate = data.map(item => {
    return (
        newArr.push(item),
        new1.map(items => {
            return (
                new1.push(items)
            )
        })
    )
})
```

then how to manipulate "data" into "transformedArray"

Comment: Would you mind explaining your code? It doesn't make that much sense (at least for me)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). If your browser or version of Node.js does not yet natively support this function, you can include a simple polyfill below, based on [the specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.flatmap):

```js
if (!Array.prototype.flatMap) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'flatMap', {
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: function flatMap (callback, thisArg = undefined) {
      return this.reduce((array, ...args) => {
        const element = callback.apply(thisArg, args);

        if (Array.isArray(element)) array.push(...element);
        else array.push(element);

        return array;
      }, []);
    }
  });
}

const data = [{name:'Movies',info:'category_name',content:[{name:'Interstellar',info:'category_data'},{name:'Dark Knight',info:'category_data'}]},{name:'Music',info:'category_name',content:[{name:'Adams',info:'category_data'},{name:'Nirvana',info:'category_data'}]},{name:'Places',info:'category_name',content:[{name:'Jordan',info:'category_data'},{name:'Punjab',info:'category_data'}]}];
const transformedArray = data.flatMap(({ content, ...o }) => [o, ...content]);

console.log(transformedArray);
```

Comment: it is returning "TypeError: data.flatMap is not a function"

Comment: @KhadamIkhwanus it's a relatively new function in the specification, you might need a polyfill depending on what browser you're using. I'll update my answer to include that in just a second.

Comment: i'm do it in my terminal and using node js version 10.16.3

Comment: thankyou somuch brother you made my day ,but why i can't use flatmap directly ? is it the my node js problem or anything else ?

Comment: @KhadamIkhwanus your version of Node.js is not problematic, it just doesn't support ES2019 specification. I believe `flatMap` support isn't available until Node v12.x.

Comment: the only improvement I would do here would be to change `o` to some other letter to avoid confusion visually with `0` in some fonts

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss `o` is a common abbreviation for a generic object. If your editor's font cannot differentiate `o` from `0`, I suggest you find a different font that can.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this using `reduce` method and spread syntax `...`.

```js
var data = [{"name":"Movies","info":"category_name","content":[{"name":"Interstellar","info":"category_data"},{"name":"Dark Knight","info":"category_data"}]},{"name":"Music","info":"category_name","content":[{"name":"Adams","info":"category_data"},{"name":"Nirvana","info":"category_data"}]},{"name":"Places","info":"category_name","content":[{"name":"Jordan","info":"category_data"},{"name":"Punjab","info":"category_data"}]}]

const result = data.reduce((r, {content, ...rest}) => {
  r.push({...rest}, ...content)
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

You can also use `concat` and `reduce` instead of spread syntax.

```js
var data = [{"name":"Movies","info":"category_name","content":[{"name":"Interstellar","info":"category_data"},{"name":"Dark Knight","info":"category_data"}]},{"name":"Music","info":"category_name","content":[{"name":"Adams","info":"category_data"},{"name":"Nirvana","info":"category_data"}]},{"name":"Places","info":"category_name","content":[{"name":"Jordan","info":"category_data"},{"name":"Punjab","info":"category_data"}]}]
const result = data.reduce((r, {content, ...rest}) => r.concat(rest, content), []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: this is precisely what `.flatMap` does

Comment: flatmap cannot be used in my console , i think this might work ,but can you explain where r and rest came from

Comment: `r` is the accumulator parameter and next parameter is current object in iteration so we use parameter destructuring to get the content property and also rest parameter to get the rest of the properties.

Comment: @Khadam Ikhwanus For better understanding you could also do this https://jsfiddle.net/t28uy79g/1/