# Using map and filter to get an array of indices corresponding to 'true' values in a boolean mask

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, indexing, filter

I am working on a Google Spreadsheet where I want to do the following action:

I have 2 row ranges: 'source' and 'dest'. In the 'source' range there are 6 cells that represent dice so they have values between 1 and 6.

My problem is to create a function that essentially copies any of the dice that have a value below some number to the 'dest' range.

My original solution was a loop through the 'source' range using `copyTo` as follows:

```
function discard_lesser_dice(cutoff_value){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var source = ss.getRangeByName('source');
  var dest = ss.getRangeByName('dest');

  for (var i = 1; i <= statusrow.getNumColumns(); i++) {   
    var srccell = source.getCell(1, i);
    if (srccell.getValue() < cuttoff_value)){
      srccell.copyTo(get_next_available_cell(dest));
    }
  }
}

function get_next_available_cell(range){
  for (var i = 1; 1 <= range.getNumColumns(); i++){
    var cell = range.getCell(1, i)
    if (cell.isBlank()){
      return cell
    }
  }
}
```

This does the job, but a bit slower than I would like, due to the number of `.getCell` calls I suspect. In the interest of learning more Google Apps Script/Javascript (I'm more familiar with Python/R) I am trying to streamline this code using `map` and `filter` methods instead as follows (and this seems to actually work):

```
function discard_lesser_dice(cutoff_value){ 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getRangeByName('source');
  var dest = ss.getRangeByName('dest');

  var sourcevals = source.getValues()[0];
  var destvals = dest.getValues()[0];

  // true if value should be discarded
  var mask_source = sourcevals.map((x) => (x < cutoff_value));

  // true if spot is available
  var mask_dest = destvals.map((x) => (x == ''));

  var source_indices = mask_source.map((bool, i) => bool ? i : -1).filter(i => i !== -1);
  var dest_indices = mask_dest.map((bool, i) => bool ? i : -1).filter(i => i !== -1);

  source_indices.forEach((x, i) => source.getCell(1, x+1).copyTo(dest.getCell(1, dest_indices[i]+1)))

}
```

My main question is, is this approach missing some tools that would have been better to use here?

The main thought I have is that the method of getting an array of indices of the 'true' values in a mask seems to be pretty hacky (i.e. `mask.map((bool, i) => bool ? i : -1).filter(i => i !== -1)` which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50981806/javascript-get-indices-of-true-values-in-a-boolean-array))

Is there a proper way to do this? Or do I need to do this at all in this scenario and am missing a more obvious way to solve the problem? Thanks for your help if
you don't mind offering it.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you wish to do:

```
function movebelowN(n) {
  var n=n||6;
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const srg=sh.getRange(1,1,1,6);
  const drg=sh.getRange(2,1,1,6);
  let dvs=drg.getValues();
  let svs=srg.getValues();
  svs.forEach(function(d,i){
    d.forEach(function(v,j){
      if(v<n){
        dvs[i][j]=v;
      }else{
        dvs[i][j]='';
      }
    });
  });
  drg.setValues(dvs);
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, that looks like a good solution; except I dont want to have any blanks in the `drg` and wouldn't this leave those there with the `dvs[i][j] = ''` statement? I am also trying to get formatting (background, font, etc.) to move with it, which is why I was resorting to the copyTo function. I suppose I could have arrays with color, fontname, fontsize, and use setBackground, etc. but thought that might be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I think [copyFormatToRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyformattorangesheet,-column,-columnend,-row,-rowend) would do the trick here. Do the cells have a different formats?