# Find all instances of array where condition is met, rather than just the first

Tags: javascript

I can't actually find a solution after browsing the internet and making some tests. I'm trying to find the indexes of where there are most 0s together. For example, this should return 3 and 6:

```
var arr1 = [1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1];
var joined1 = arr1.join(''); // "1010010011"
var ans = joined1.indexOf("00"); // returns 3 - want to return 3 & 6
```

And this should return 1 and 5:

```
var arr2 = [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1];
var joined2 = arr2.join(''); // "10001000100111"
var ans2 = joined2.indexOf("000"); // returns 1 - want to return 1 & 5
```

The problem is that indexOf only returns the first index rather than both. How can I get it to return all instances where the condition is satisfied? thanks for any help

Comment: Possible duplicate. Look here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798477/how-to-find-index-of-all-occurrences-of-element-in-array)

Comment: You have to loop over it more than once and use the startFrom parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're looking more at string operations and not array operations. In this case [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) can help you. Specifically function arguments for [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter). Note that the code below does not escape special regular expression characters like `.`

```
function findAll(string, value) {
    var indices = [];
    string.replace(new RegExp(value, "g"), function (m, o) {
        indices.push(o);
    });
    return indices;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. What part does "g" play here? and the 'm' in the function? I'm trying to understand how this works!

Comment: The `g` stands for global and means to match every instance of the string. The `m` is the part that is matched but we don't need it. However, since it is the first argument we have to include it.

Answer (score 1):

This works. Search the string from reverse, store the index and get the substring on which it should be iterated again.

```js
function findIndexes(arr, value)
{
    var str = arr.join(''), index = 0, result = [];
    while(index>-1)
    {
        index = str.lastIndexOf(value)
        index>-1 && (result.push(index), str = str.substring(0,index-1));
    }
    return result.reverse();
}

console.log(findIndexes([1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1],"00"));
console.log(findIndexes([1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1],"000"));
console.log(findIndexes([1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1],"0000"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a general solution to find the indexes of n consecutive matches, just first index of a consecutive match or all index of a consecutive match:

```js
function findIndexOfElements(arr, search, times, allkeys) {
  var indexs = []
  let consecutives = 0;
  arr.map((o, i) => {
    if (o == search) { //<--we find what we are looking for
      if (allkeys) {
        indexs.push(i); //<--store all indexes
      } else if (consecutives == 0) {
        indexs.push(i); //<--store just first index
      }
      consecutives++;
    } else { //<--we don't find what we are looking for
      if (consecutives < times && consecutives > 0) {
        if (allkeys) {
          indexs.splice(-consecutives, consecutives); //<--remove all consecutives
        } else {
          indexs.splice(-1, 1); //<--remove just the last index
        }
      }
      consecutives = 0;
    }
  })
  return indexs;
}
var arr1 = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1];
var arr2 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1];
var arr3 = ["cat", "cat", "dog", "cat", "dog", "dog", "cat", "cat"];
//just index of first match
console.log(findIndexOfElements(arr1, 0, 2, false)) //[ 3, 6 ]
console.log(findIndexOfElements(arr2, 0, 3, false)) //[ 1, 5 ]
console.log(findIndexOfElements(arr3, "cat", 2, false)) //[ 0, 6 ]
//all indexes of match
console.log(findIndexOfElements(arr1, 0, 2, true)) //[ 3, 4, 6, 7 ]
console.log(findIndexOfElements(arr2, 0, 3, true)) //[ 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7 ]
console.log(findIndexOfElements(arr3, "cat", 2, true)) //[ 0, 1, 6, 7 ]
```