# How to get multiple indexes of array by a value in pure JavaScript (value exact matching)

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I'm trying to make indexOf return me multiple indexes of array's items which value equal "1" (exactly matching).

Here's what I'm doing:

```
var arr = [1, 11, 1, 111, 1111, 11, 1, 1111, 11];
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  console.log(arr.findIndex(1, i));
}
```

Result which I expect is:
0
2
6

But actually I get "-1" value after mentioned indexes. I'm assuming that it's related to array's
values (each of them include "1" but not equals to "1"). When I'm doing the same with array of
different values, it works as desired.

Does it really related to values? If yes, how to solve this problem?
If there are more proper ways to find multiple array's indexes by a value (with exact match), it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find index of all occurrences of element in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798477/how-to-find-index-of-all-occurrences-of-element-in-array)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the array to array of indexes, which value is `1`:

```js
const arr = [1, 11, 1, 111, 1111, 11, 1, 1111, 11];

const indexes = arr.reduce((r, n, i) => {
  n === 1 && r.push(i);
  
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(indexes);
```

You can also use `indexOf` and a `while` loop, to start search from the last found index, and stop when the index is `-1`:

```js
const arr = [1, 11, 1, 111, 1111, 11, 1, 1111, 11];

let i = -1;
const indexes = [];

while(i = arr.indexOf(1, i + 1), i !== -1) indexes.push(i);

console.log(indexes);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to do it with Pure JavaScript. I've added some of them.

Using [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var arr = [1, 11, 1, 111, 1111, 11, 1, 1111, 11];
var keys = [];
var filtered = arr.filter((e, i) => {
  if (e === 1) {
    keys.push(i);
  }
});
console.log(keys);
```

Using [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var arr = [1, 11, 1, 111, 1111, 11, 1, 1111, 11];
var keys = [];
arr.forEach((e,i)=>{
  if(e === 1){
    keys.push(i);
  }
});
console.log(keys);
```

Using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var arr = [1, 11, 1, 111, 1111, 11, 1, 1111, 11];
var keys = [];
arr.reduce(function(a, e, i) {
  if (e === 1)
    keys.push(i);
  return keys;
}, [])

console.log(keys);
```