# Why does Array.filter(Number) filter zero out in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, numbers, typeof

I'm trying to filter all non-numeric elements out from an array. We can see the desired output when using typeof. But with Number, it filters zero out.

Here's the example (tested in Chrome Console):

```
[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, Number(0), '', 'test'].filter(Number)
// Which output with zero filtered out:
[-1, 1, 2, 3, 4]  // 0 is filtered
```

If we use typeof, it doesn't filter zero, which was expected.

```
// code
[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, Number(0), '', 'test'].filter(n => typeof n === 'number')
// output
[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
```

My question:

1. What is the difference between the 'Number' and 'typeof' approaches?
2. Number filters zero, but 'Number' itself literally contains zero, and this confuses me.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Because `0` is one of the many [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values in javascript

All these conditions will be sent to `else` blocks:

```
if (false)
if (null)
if (undefined)
if (0)
if (NaN)
if ('')
if ("")
if (``)
```

From the [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) documentation:

> `filter()` calls a provided `callback` function once for each element in an array, and constructs a new array of all the values for which callback returns a **value that coerces to true**

In your case the callback function is the `Number`. So your code is equivalent to:

```
[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, Number(0), '', 'test'].filter(a => Number(a)) 

// Number(0) -> 0
// Number(Number(0)) -> 0
// Number('') -> 0
// Number('test') -> NaN
```

When `filter` function picks [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) values (or values that coerces to `true`), the items which return `0` and `NaN` are ignored. So, it returns `[-1, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: Notice that `new Boolean(false)` is truthy, as well as an empty object (`{}`) and an empty array (`[]`).

Answer (score 17):

To prevent a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) zero from filtering, you could use another callback for getting only numerical values: [`Number.isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite)

```js
console.log([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, Number(0), '', 'test'].filter(Number.isFinite))
```

Comment: Note that unlike `Number('1')` which returns `1`, a truthy value, `Number.isFinite('1')` returns `false`.

Answer (score 5):

## Expected behavior

This behavior isn't unique to using Number as the filter function. A filter function that simple returns the `0` value would also remove it from the list.

```js
var a = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, Number(0), '', 'test'].filter(v => v)
console.log(a); // [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, "test"]
```

This is because [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) isn't specifically a filter function, it's primarily a type-casting function (and a class constructor, but not a very useful one). So when a number (like `0`) is passed to `Number`, it just returns that number.

[`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) removes values that are [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). In JavaScript, the following are falsy and thus removed by `filter`.

```
false
null
undefined
0
NaN
''
""
``
```

(For complicated backwards compatibility reasons [MDN goes into](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy#Examples), `document.all` is also falsy in many browsers despite being an object, but that's a side-note)

Comment: Use Number.isFinite instead of Number will be more semantic in code.

Answer (score 4):

Zero is a falsey value. The typeof is always returning a boolean value. When the number 0 is returned, it is returning to the test, and therefore coming back as false, so the number zero is filtered out.

Answer (score 4):

It's because 0 is a falsy value which returns false, and anything that returns false to the filter function is filtered out of the new array.

#### Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Answer (score 3):

When you're using Number in filter, Actually it is passing each item of Array to Number constructor and in case of string or 0 Number will return NaN or 0 and both of them are false so filter is filtering out both of them

whereas when you're using typeof then 0 has "number" type so it is returning true and filter method doesn't filtering it out

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this behavior is that `0, null, undefined, NaN` is equivalent to false in JavaScript so, in the first case:

```
[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, Number(0), '', 'test'].filter(Number);
```

when used Number as one of the params in the filter, it returns the number itself. So when 0 is passed it returns 0 which javascript understands as `false`. So, it returns

```
[-1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So to be on the safe side it is advised to use `Number.isFinite` instead of just `Number`.

```
[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, Number(0), '', 'test'].filter(Number.isFinite);
```

Gives same results as

```
[-1,0,1,2,3,4, Number(0), '','test'].filter(n=> typeof n === 'number');
```

would give.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example showing how to remove multiple indices from an Array of numbers, and dealing with the 0:

```js
const array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
console.log('init', array)

const indicesToDel = [2, 3, 5, 9]
console.log('indices to del', indicesToDel)

let result = array.filter( (item, index) => !indicesToDel.includes(index) ? Number.isFinite(item) : false )
console.log('result', result)
```