# why arrow function gives different result that inline callback function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, callback, arrow-functions

I want to remove everything from an array but numbers, so I wrote this code:

```js
// test array
let array = [NaN, 0, 15, false, -22, '', undefined, 47, null];

// using arrow function
let a = array.filter((val) => typeof val === 'number');
// outputs: [ NaN, 0, 15, -22, 47 ]

// using inLine callBack function
let b = array.filter(function (val) {
    if (typeof val === 'number') {
        return val;
    }
})
// outputs: [ NaN, 0, 15, -22, 47 ]
```

so my question is, how are they different, and why did they output different results.

p.s. I am new to JS :)

Comment: `if (typeof val === 'number') { return val; }` is not the same as `return typeof val === 'number'`. Nothing related to the type of function.

Comment: This has nothing to do with arrow vs. regular function; in your second attempt you're returning the `val` if it's a number, so if `val` is falsey (NaN and 0 are), it gets removed. To make both functions identical you need to remove the `if` and simply `return typeof val === 'number';`

Comment: Aside: [`array.filter(Number.isFinite)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53920037/why-does-array-filternumber-filter-zero-out-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, my bad :(

as mentioned in the comments:

```js
if (typeof val === 'number') {
  return val;
}
```

```js
return typeof val === 'number';
```

these two things are NOT the same.