# Saving into new array all indexes of other array elements which meet condition using .findIndex

Tags: javascript, arrays, array.prototype.map

```
const jumbledNums = [123, 7, 25, 78, 5, 9]; 

const lessThanTen = jumbledNums.findIndex(num => {
  return num < 10;
});
```

Hi,
my problem is that this snippet is returning only first met index of element meeting condition `num < 10` , but I want to save all indexes meeting condition into new array. From what I have read on Mozilla documentation of `.findIndex()`, it doesn't check other elements after it finds an element which meeting a condition. Is there any way I can reiterate `.findIndex` over every element in the array (e.g. using `.map()`) or I need to use another method to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find index of all occurrences of element in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798477/how-to-find-index-of-all-occurrences-of-element-in-array)

Comment: A question you linked as a possible duplicate asks for indexes of all occurrences of an element, when I am asking for indexes of all elements which are meeting condition in this case num<10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map first either the index if smaller than ten or `-1` then filter the index array for valid indices.

```js
const
    jumbledNums = [123, 7, 25, 78, 5, 9],
    lessThanTen = jumbledNums
        .map((v, i) => v < 10 ? i : -1)
        .filter(i => i !== -1);

console.log(lessThanTen);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Array#reduce()`

```js
const jumbledNums = [123, 7, 25, 78, 5, 9];

const lessThanTen = jumbledNums.reduce((a, c, i) => (c < 10 ? a.concat(i) : a), [])

console.log(lessThanTen)
```

Comment: It is working, but I don't understand code. You are checking values by condition c < 10, alright. But why merging indexes with accumulator is working?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), which will return a new array which will check the condition. To get the values

But array.filter doesn't return index, so you can use [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which will create a new array and you can use array.filter to remove the undefined cases.

I hope this will solve the issue.

```js
const jumbledNums = [123, 7, 25, 78, 5, 9]; 

const lessThan10 = jumbledNums.filter(o => o<10)

console.log("array with less than 10", lessThan10)

const lessThan10Indexes = jumbledNums.map((o,i) =>{ 
  return o < 10 ? i : undefined
}).filter(o => o)

console.log("array with less than 10 Indexes", lessThan10Indexes)
```

Comment: Expected results is index not value

Comment: zero is a valid index, but falsy.

Comment: const jumbledNums = [3, 123, 7, 25, 78, 5, 9]; , why array.filter is the issue. I didn't checked that. First time i am noticing that any idea on that. Is that array.filter , filters falsy values