# How to avoid accessing same index when most values of array are same? Take a look

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I am trying to solve a problem related to javascript algorithms.
Here's the problem.
I want to access the index of an array value by indexOf() method.
But I want to know how can I avoid the same index when most values in the array are the same.
Take example:

`let arr1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1];`

Now as you can see most of the values are same and indexOf method looks for an index of a given value in the array.

`arr1.indexOf(arr1[0]); // 0
 arr1.indexOf(arr1[5]); // 5`

So, it will return 0 as the system but when I will going to move further to access the next value.
Like:

`arr1.indexOf(arr1[1]); // 0
 arr1.indexOf(arr1[6]); // 5`

It returns the same as before. But I want the next index instead of same.
Ex:

`arr1.indexOf(arr1[1]); // 1`

It should return 1 because 0 is already returned one time.
So, what is the solution to this?

Comment: Maybe just `slice` the array at the current index first? Not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Could you show us expected results for an input of `[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]`?

Comment: Given that `arr[0] === arr[1]`, those two values are not distinguishable for `indexOf`. There is no solution - you have to pass around the index itself, not the array value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) have a second parameter, the starting index.

You can do :

```js
let arr1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1];
console.log(arr1.indexOf(arr1[1], 1)); // 1
```

---

**Edit**

If you want all index for a specific value, like `0` you can do this :

```js
let arr1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1];

function getAllIndexes(arr, val) {
  var indexes = [],
    i = -1;
  while ((i = arr.indexOf(val, i + 1)) != -1) {
    indexes.push(i);
  }
  return indexes;
}

var indexes = getAllIndexes(arr1, 0);

console.log(indexes);
```

With this script you get an array with all index of a value in an array.

Reference of the script : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20798567/3083093

Answer (score -1):

The `indexOf(value)` method returns the **position of the first occurrence** of a specified **value** in a string.

You can use `indexOf(value, start)`. 
Here, **start** is the position to start the search