# Gather object list data by multiple types with ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have this data:

```
const data = [
  { state: 'state1', zone: 'zone1', length: 22 },
  { state: 'state1', zone: 'zone1', length: 10 },
  { state: 'state1', zone: 'zone2', length: 66 },
  { state: 'state2', zone: 'zone1', length: 122 },
  { state: 'state2', zone: 'zone2', length: 32 },
  { state: 'state1', zone: 'zone2', length: 12}
  ...
  { state: 'stateN', zone: 'zoneN', length: X },
]
```

I don't know the number of state values and zone values, it can be infinite.

I would like this:

```
[
  { state: 'state1', data: [32, 66] },
  { state: 'state2', data: [122, 44] },
  ...
]
```

Where data have the sum of the lengths of each zone in ascending order.

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

### Update

OriDrori pointed out that I was missing the group-by-zones step.  That makes the code a bit longer, but still relatively clear:

```js
const extract = pipe (
  groupBy (prop ('state')),
  map (groupBy (prop ('zone'))),
  map (map (pluck ('length'))),
  map (map (sum)),
  map (values),
  toPairs,
  map (zipObj (['state', 'levels']))
)

const data = [{state: 'state1', zone: 'zone1', length: 22}, {state: 'state1', zone: 'zone1', length: 10}, {state: 'state1', zone: 'zone2', length: 66}, {state: 'state2', zone: 'zone1', length: 122}, {state: 'state2', zone: 'zone2', length: 32}, {state: 'state1', zone: 'zone2', length: 12}, /*  ... */ {state: 'stateN', zone: 'zoneN', length: 5}]

console .log (extract (data))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, groupBy, prop, map, pluck, sum, values, toPairs, zipObj} = R </script>
```

We start and finish as below, but in between, we group each state by zone, calculate our sum of lengths on that result, then pass the `values` of those sums into the next step to rework into the final format.

**Note**: this does not quite match your requested output, but would if the last `"state1"` was instead `"state2"`.  Is that just a typo?

### Original Answer

(This is superseded by the above.)

I would probably do it like this in Ramda:

```js
const extract = pipe (
  groupBy (prop ('state')), 
  map (pluck ('length')),
  toPairs,
  map (zipObj (['state', 'length']))
)

const data = [{state: 'state1', zone: 'zone1', length: 22}, {state: 'state1', zone: 'zone1', length: 10}, {state: 'state1', zone: 'zone2', length: 66}, {state: 'state2', zone: 'zone1', length: 122}, {state: 'state2', zone: 'zone2', length: 32}, {state: 'state1', zone: 'zone2', length: 12}, /*  ... */ {state: 'stateN', zone: 'zoneN', length: 'X'}]

console .log (extract (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, groupBy, prop, map, pluck, toPairs, zipObj} = R </script>
```

We first group the objects by state, then for each group, collect the `length` properties, turn this to an array of `[state, lengths]` pairs and the map over this array turning the elements into your output objects.  This is how I usually work with Ramda, creating a pipeline of transformations.

Comment: @OriDrori: Thanks.  Missed that.  Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Group by the `state`, and the map each group, and apply a spec to it. The state is the 2nd param (the key) when using `R.mapObjIndexed`. The `data` requires grouping the items in the state's group by the `zone`, and summing the `lengths`.

```js
const { pipe, groupBy, prop, map, pluck, sum, values, sort, mapObjIndexed, applySpec, nthArg, subtract } = R

const sumZones = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('zone')), // group by the zone 
  map(pipe(pluck('length'),  sum)), // sum the results in each zone
  values, // convert to an array of values
  sort(subtract) // sort the items if needed
)

const fn = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('state')), // group by the state prop
  mapObjIndexed(applySpec({ // convert each group to an object
    state: nthArg(1), // get the state's name from the 2nd arg - index 1
    data: sumZones // sum the length of the zone in each state
  })),
  values, // convert the object of objects to an array of objects
)

const data = [{state: 'state1', zone: 'zone1', length: 22}, {state: 'state1', zone: 'zone1', length: 10}, {state: 'state1', zone: 'zone2', length: 66}, {state: 'state2', zone: 'zone1', length: 122}, {state: 'state2', zone: 'zone2', length: 32}, {state: 'state1', zone: 'zone2', length: 12}, /*  ... */ {state: 'stateN', zone: 'zoneN', length: 'X'}]

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's interesting to see the difference and similarities in our approaches.  I'm curious about why you include the `sort`.

Comment: This line was a bit misleading - "Where data have the sum of the lengths of each zone in ascending order.", so I've included it with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const data = [
  { state: 'state1', zone: 'zone1', length: 22 },
  { state: 'state1', zone: 'zone1', length: 10 },
  { state: 'state1', zone: 'zone2', length: 66 },
  { state: 'state2', zone: 'zone1', length: 122 },
  { state: 'state2', zone: 'zone2', length: 32 },
  { state: 'state1', zone: 'zone2', length: 12},
  { state: 'stateN', zone: 'zoneN', length: 5 }
]

function getAllIndexes(arr, val) { //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798477/how-to-find-index-of-all-occurrences-of-element-in-array
    var indexes = [], i = -1;
    while ((i = arr.indexOf(val, i+1)) != -1){
        indexes.push(i);
    }
    return indexes;
}

var states = data.map(el => el.state)
var statesUnique = states.filter((el, index) => states.indexOf(el) == index)
var indexes = []
statesUnique.forEach(el => indexes.push(getAllIndexes(states, el)))

var lengths = indexes.map(el1 => el1.map(el2 => data[el2].length).sort())

var sortedData = statesUnique.map((el, index) => {return {state:el, data:lengths[index]}})
console.log(sortedData)
```

Explanation:

I got all the unique states, and then the indexes of each element with that state. After that, I used the indexes to get the lengths of each element with that state and sorted them. Finally, I just merged the unique states with the lengths to produce the output.

Comment: Thanks ! But in data you only need 2 number for this example on for sum of length zone 1 and other for zone 2 and not all the values

Answer (score 0):

I find with Ramda

```
const getLengthSumOnEachZoneByState = R.pipe(
  R.groupBy(R.prop('state')),
  R.map(
   R.pipe(
    R.sortBy(R.prop('zone')),
    R.groupBy(R.prop('zone')),
    R.map(R.pipe(R.pluck('length'), R.sum)),
    R.values
   )
  )
)

console.log(getLengthSumOnEachZoneByState(data)) // <====== Result
```

And in native way

```
const zonesByState = data.reduce((zonesByState, zone) => {
  if (zonesByState[zone.state] == null) {
    zonesByState[zone.state] = []
  }
  zonesByState[zone.state].push(zone)
  return zonesByState
}, {})
​
const stateLengths = Object.entries(zonesByState)
  .map(([state, zones]) => {
    const lengthsByZone = zones.reduce((lengthsByZone, zone) => {
      if (lengthsByZone[zone.zone] == null) {
        lengthsByZone[zone.zone] = 0
      }
      lengthsByZone[zone.zone] += zone.length
      return lengthsByZone
    }, {})
    return {
      state,
      data: Object.values(lengthsByZone).sort()
    }
  })
  console.log(stateLengths) // <====== Result
```