# Find multiple indexes in an array

Tags: javascript

`a = [-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180]`

Given the above, how can I get another array of the indexes where `-1` is found?

I was able to do it with a for loop and checking against the desired number, then getting the number of the iteration and pushing into an array. Wondering if there's a one liner or a way that won't involve a for loop.

Comment: By a “list”, do you mean another Array?

Comment: yes, will edit to clarify

Comment: Define "cleaner way"

Comment: "Cleaner way" compared to what? What does "cleaner" mean?

Comment: just defined it with my edit

Comment: Please show us your attempt(s)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find index of all occurrences of element in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798477/how-to-find-index-of-all-occurrences-of-element-in-array)

Comment: Ave you tried any of the obvious approaches like `[...a.keys()].filter(i => a[i] === -1)`

Comment: @Wyck wasn't obvious to me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` to generate a new array of indices:

```
const a = [-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180];
console.log(a.reduce((acc, cv, idx) => {
    if (cv === -1) acc.push(idx);
    return acc;
}, []);
```