# Create an array from the output of a function inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting

I want to get the position of `"they"` and `"some"` for all occurrences of it in the array `split_Sentence` by using a for loop function. Then I want to build an array from the output of the for loop function. But the problem is that whenever I use `indexOf()` to find the position it always gives the position of the first occurence. I don't know how to create an array from the output of a for loop.
*can anybody help me out I would be grateful.*

```js
var Sentence = "some warriors know when they are defeated, whether some of them are too stubborn to accept it and they are the one who die. "
var split_Sentence = Sentence.split(" ")
/* function() ==> then sort an array listing all its output*/
```

```
Expected outcome: final array should be like this array= (0,4,8,18)
```

Please do ask me if you didn't understand my question

Comment: Please add an expected outcome to your question.(You can use regex)

Comment: why to use `for..loop`. Use `matchAll` instead.

Comment: FYI `for..loop` is not a function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find index of all occurrences of element in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798477/how-to-find-index-of-all-occurrences-of-element-in-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: do handle upper case lower case things as needed.

```js
const Sentence = "some warriors know when they are defeated, whether some of them are too stubborn to accept it and they are the one who die.";
const arrayOfIndex = Sentence
  .split(" ")
  .map((word, index) => word === "some" || word === "they" ? index : false)
  .filter(x => x !== false);
console.log({arrayOfIndex});
```

Comment: How to access the console logs? For future use?

Comment: didn't get the question, if you mean how to access these index it's simply an array, so you can access `arrayOfIndex`

Comment: @SouradipMandal F12 and ctrl+shift+j (depending on os/browser)