# Discord JS function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm building a Discord bot using a collector and am trying to collect votes for rounds of a game. <strike>However, the bot keeps returning the wrong values. It will usually return either `undefined` or `[object Object]`. The stringifier() function should be returning the name of a round but it's instead returning undefined. e.g. if I input "spleef" on Discord it should output "Spleef" to console and in Discord, but it returns undefined in both or just errors.</strike>

UPDATE: i found that the variables were returning boolean values (the variables are battleBoxVotes to cTFVotes).

UPDATE A LOT LATER: so I fixed the problem but my new problem now is that I can't get variables `bbv` to `ctfv` to not return an error if they don't have a value. Console logs this: `(node:8700) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined`

```js
const filter = m => (m.author.id != client.user.id);
      const channel = message.channel;
      const collector = channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { time: 5000 });
      collector.on('collect', m => console.log(`Collected ${m.content}`));
      collector.on('end', async collected => {

        var bb = collected.find(collected => collected.content === 'battle box');
        var pw = collected.find(collected => collected.content === 'spleef');
        var s = collected.find(collected => collected.content === 'spleef');
        var sw = collected.find(collected => collected.content === 'skywars');
        var ctf = collected.find(collected => collected.content === 'capture the flag');

        const bbv = bb.content || null;
        const pwv = pw.content || null;
        const sv = s.content || null;
        const swv = sw.content || null;
        const ctfv = ctf.content || null;

        const stringifier = function(a, b, c, d, e) {
          let results;
          if (a>b&&a>c&&a>d&&a>e) {results = "Battle Box"}
          else if (b>a&&b>c&&b>d&&b>e) {results = "Parkour Warrior"}
          else if (c>a&&c>b&&c>d&&c>e) {results = "Spleef"}
          else if (d>a&&d>b&&d>c&&d>e) {results = "SkyWars"}
          else if (e>a&&e>b&&e>c&&e>c) {results = "Capture the Flag"}
          return results;
        }

          message.channel.send(`And the winner is... ${stringifier(bbv, pwv, sv, swv, ctfv)}!`),
          console.log(stringifier(bbv, pwv, sv, swv, ctfv))

      });
```

Comment: Which `values` are wrong / undefined? Clarify this in your question

Comment: The `results` variable being returned from the `stringifier()` function is returning undefined, amended in post.

Comment: Can you debug your `stringifier` function and check if all parameters are valid?

Comment: Because I just tested this function locally and it worked

Comment: It appears that the variables (`battleBoxVotes` to `cTFVotes`) are returning boolean values not numbers.

Comment: I tried this: `console.log(stringify(1,2,3,4,5,6))` and the output was `Capture the flag`

Comment: thanks for pointing out! Idk why I didn't see that... all of these values are `boolean` because `.some()` returns either `true` or `false`

Comment: My mistake, I used `1,2,3,4,5`

Comment: Try replacing `.find()` with `.some()`

Comment: `.find()` i think returns a single value, but i'll try it :)

Comment: Yeah but `.some()` will only check if a specific `value` is included in your array and return a bool. But your function is taking numbers as parameters

Comment: I changed it to `.find()` and it is still returning undefined.

Comment: If you debug the function, how do the parameters look?

Comment: sorry i dont really know what you mean by "debug the function", i don't talk to other developers much :D

i had a look inside the function `stringifier()` though, if thats what you mean, and it's either not recieving the values or the logic inside it is wrong. thinking that it is probably the values.

Comment: Then you can add `console.log(a, b, c, d, e)`  above the `let result` line, run it and tell me what the output is

Comment: woah, that output a long one , it can't fit in my console! i'll send as much as i can, but it's looking like every one of the values are the exact same message. i think the values must not be filtering the messages and just taking every single one as an input.

Comment: Seems like you're passing `objects` to the function and not single numbers. In that case you have to determine the value you want to store from an `object`

Comment: Oh thanks! I think that might be it :)

Comment: E.g. your `objects` looks like this: `const someObject = { key: 1, value: hello }` and you want to store the `value`, you want to do this: `const result = someObject.value`

Comment: I **assume** that your parameters are `objects` but I can't tell because I didn't see your log output yet

Comment: i can't paste in the logs because they don't fit in the text box (or my terminal window for that matter). sorry :/, i think you've hit the nail on the head though, am fixing as we speak

Comment: If you dont know much about `objects` you can check out [this guide](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)

Comment: And you can also post a screenshot of the output

Comment: it won't fit on my screen :P

Comment: Well, that's a lot xD

Comment: so i fixed the issue with the objects but my newest problem is with the values again. i updated the post, you don't happen to know how to fix this?

Comment: Try replacing this `const bbv = bb.content || null;` to this `const bbv = bb ? bb.content : null` and add code to your `stringify` function that checks all parameters. If one of these is `null`, say `return`

Comment: okay so i did that, and it returns undefined again. i removed the line in the `stringify()` function to check if `null` just as a test, this also returned null. so i went inside the function and logged the paramaters, i got this: `null spleef spleef null null`. so for some reason the `pwv` variable is also checking for spleef. i changed that (it was a typo at the start xD) and ran it again, this time putting in two discord inputs to check - mostly fine. the problem is, it only collects one of each value. any ideas how i could count the values instead of outputting the message content itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233232/discussion-between-toasty-and-hanatic).

Comment: If you're using node v14+, you can use optional chaining (`bbv?.content`, `pwv?.content`, etc.) Otherwise, check if the values are null using the ternary operator (`bbv ? bbv.content : null`, `pwv ? pwv.content : null`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The logic of that comparison absolutely breaks my brain and is a pain to read in the first place. Here's an adapted version that should work a bit better.

This solution iterates through the recieved messages and increments a counter for each gamemode depending on a [switch-case expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). (bear in mind this doesn't stop a user from simply spamming whichever gamemode they want...)

[Credit for the `getAllIndexes` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20798567/10521934) (used to determine ties)

```js
const filter = m => (m.author.id != client.user.id);
const channel = message.channel;
const collector = channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { time: 5000 });
collector.on('collect', m => console.log(`Collected ${m.content}`));
collector.on('end', async collected => {
    let msgs = Array.from(collected.keys()).map(m=>m?.content.toLowerCase().trim());
    let modes = [ "Battle Box", "Parkour Warrior", "Spleef", "SkyWars", "Capture the Flag" ] // Define the names of the GameModes
    let scores = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] // Set up the default scores
    msgs.forEach(m => {
        switch(m) {
        case "bb": // Fallthrough case for aliases
        case "battlebox":
        case "battle box":
            scores[0]++; // Increment BattleBox (0) Counter
            break;
        case "pw":
        case "parkour":
        case "parkour warrior":
            scores[1]++; // Increment ParkourWarrior (1) counter
            break;
        case "spleef":
            scores[2]++; // Increment Spleef (2) counter
            break;
        case "sw":
        case "sky":
        case "skywars":
            scores[3]++; // Increment SkyWars (3) counter
            break;
        case "ctf":
        case "capture the flag":
            scores[4]++; // Increment CaptureTheFlag (4) counter
            break;
    });

    // Now to find who won...
    let winningCount = Math.max(scores);
    let winningIndexes = getAllIndexes(scores, winningCount);

    if(winningIndexes.length = 1) { // Single Winner
        message.channel.send(`And the winner is... ${modes[winningIndexes[0]]}!`);
    } else { // tie!
       message.channel.send(`It's a tie! There were ${winningIndexes.length} winners. (${winningIndexes.map(i=>modes[i]).join(", ")})`);
    }
j});


// Get All Indexes function...
function getAllIndexes(arr, val) {
    var indexes = [], i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if (arr[i] === val) indexes.push(i);
    return indexes;
}
```