# How do I remove all multiple values ​in JavaScript?

Tags: sorting, duplicates

For Example my input Array = [1,2,3,2,3,5]
I want this array as output, where I want to remove all the numbers that repeat.
output Array = [1,5]
How do I remove all multiple values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Comment: I want uniqueness as if any number repeats I want to remove both duplicate numbers, For Example, Array = [2,2,3,4,5,5] Output should be outPutArray = [3,5]

Answer (score 0):

I would combine the following two answers:

[Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

[How to find index of all occurrences of element in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798477/how-to-find-index-of-all-occurrences-of-element-in-array/41271541)

```js
function getAllIndexes(arr, val) {
    var indexes = [], i = -1;
    while ((i = arr.indexOf(val, i+1)) != -1){
        indexes.push(i);
    }
    return indexes;
}

function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return getAllIndexes(self, value).length == 1
}

var inputArray = [1,2,3,2,3,5]
inputArray = inputArray.filter(onlyUnique)
console.log(inputArray)
```

Comment: Can you please explain the above code, as I am a beginner and I cannot understand the above code, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use set and spread operator I believe

```
uniq = [...new Set(array)];
```