# Tick Tack Toe: Filter multidimensional array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am learning to filter nested arrays in javascript and I believe this example can help me to understand it better. below is the object.

```
const game = () => {
return {
    player1: {
        username: 'ABC',
        playingAs: 'X'
    },
    player2: {
        username: 'XYZ',
        playingAs: '0'
    },
    board: 
        [
            ['✓', null, 'X'],
            ['X', '✓', null],
            ['✓', null, 'X']
        ]   

   }
};
```

my code is below

```
const {player1: {username: PlayerA, playingAs:PlayerAMark}, player2: {username: PlayerB, playingAs:PlayerBMark}} = game();
const {board: board} = game();

//is there any efficient way to do it without a loop using a filter?
for (const item in board) {
    //One approach which comes to my mind is to loop. but that is what I don't think would be a learning curve for me.

}
```

I am trying something like this

```
const array = board;
for (const item in board) {
    console.log(array.filter(innerArray => innerArray[item] !== 'X'));
}
```

I am focused on implementing some efficient way that can help me to return

```
Player1 marked 'X' at 3,1,3 and
Player 2 marked '0' at location at 0,2,1
```

I am only stuck with filtering this board multidimensional array.

I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Please show us your attempt.

Comment: `filter` does a loop internally, so you don’t save any loop using `filter`.

Comment: You should use `filter` only if you really want to get an array that only includes specific elements of the original array.

Comment: Also, You need to consider how You interpret results. Eg. `Player1 marked 'X' at 1,2,3` could mean that all three items are on first row, or first X is on second line, and two other on third line.

Comment: @83lynx, Board has three objects. and in each object, there is an array, right? so I want to find the position of X inside each array

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `reduce` function. We can have the desired output using this code:

```
function printForPlayer(player, board) {
var indexes = board.reduce((acc,row)=>[...row.reduce((acc2,item,index) => item==player.playingAs ? [...acc2,index+1] : acc2, []),...acc], [])
console.log(`${player.username} marked ${player.playingAs} at ${indexes.join(',')}`)
}

printForPlayer(game().player1, game().board);
printForPlayer(game().player2, game().board);
```

this is a bit complex, but it works without loop

Answer (score 0):

One way is to loop over each row to create an array with all the places where the player has his own symbol.

Using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), we can [find all the indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20798754/5625547) of the symobl of the current player, then after the loop, use [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to show it.

```js
const data = {player1: {username: 'ABC', playingAs: 'X'}, player2: {username: 'XYZ', playingAs: '0'}, board: [['0', null, 'X'], ['X', '0', null], ['0', null, 'X'] ] };
const logPlayer = (player) => {
    const ox = data[player].playingAs;
    let indexes = [];
    
    for (let row in data.board) {
        const ii = data.board[row].reduce((prev, cur, i) => (cur === ox) ? [ ...prev, i ] : prev,[]);
        if (ii.length > 0) ii.map(i => indexes.push(`${+row + 1}-${i + 1}`));
    }
    console.log(`${player} has placed an '${ox}' on the following places (row-column)`, indexes.join(", "));
}

logPlayer('player1');
logPlayer('player2');
```

```
player1 has placed an 'X' on the following places (row-column) 1-3, 2-1, 3-3
player2 has placed an '0' on the following places (row-column) 1-1, 2-2, 3-1
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is my solution which worked for me.

First of all, null is always rendered as 0. So I hade to update my array as mentioned below

```
    board: 
        [
            ['✓', null, 'X'],
            ['X', '✓', null],
            ['✓', null, 'X']
        ]
```

Secondly, after updating the board value in the array, the following solution worked for me.

```
const {
        player1: {username: PlayerA, playingAs:PlayerAMark}, 
        player2: {username: PlayerB, playingAs:PlayerBMark}, 
        board: GameBoard
    } = game();

let array = GameBoard.entries();
let tick = [];
let cross = [];
for (const [index,element] of array) {
    tick.push(element.indexOf(PlayerBMark)+ 1);
    cross.push(element.indexOf(PlayerAMark)+ 1);
}
 
console.log('Player ', PlayerA, ' Clicked ', PlayerAMark ,' at '+ cross);
console.log('Player ',PlayerB, ' Clicked ', PlayerBMark ,' at '+ tick);
```

Here is the result for this.

```
Player  ABC  Clicked  X  at 3,1,3
Player  XYZ  Clicked  ✓  at 1,2,1
```

Thanks everyone for all the help. But, still I am looking for ***How we can improve its performance and avoided looping?***

Thanks again.